# I have a ppk key file open in Notepad, but I do not remember it's passphrase. Can I retrieve the passphrase?

Tags: putty, ssl, openssh, openssl, private-key

Basically the heading, I created a private key file using PuTTY a few days back and forgot the passphrase. Luckily, the file is still open in Notepad. I can see it's contents, but I cannot open it in PuTTYgen because I don't remember the passphrase. Is there any way to retrieve that given I can see the contents of the ppk file?

Answer (score 3):

The ppk key file format is plain text, even when encrypted. The encryption does not prevent you from opening it in Notepad or any other application.

But having the key opened in Notepad does not help you at all with retrieving the actual key. If you do not remember the passphrase, there's no way to recover your key (except for a brute-force attack, which is hardly feasible for you).

You will have to create a new key pair.